# How do I setup my server to precompile lessCSS with node?

Tags: css, node.js, less

I just started using lessCSS and I think its great, but I would prefer to run it server side. I've read that node.js is the best way to do this, but I have never used it before and honestly have no idea how to set it up.

So how can I setup node.js on my server / site, and make it precompile my .less file(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [express](http://www.expressjs.com). It allows you to select a CSS compiler.

It's also a good library for handling routing and middleware for a website.

`express --css less` should set up your less compiler.

Comment: Thank you @Raynos, but I´ve been reading the guide and have no clue about where to start. As I said, I have never used node.js before and I would need a bit of help in setting up the server for it...

Comment: @0al0 are you actually running your website from node or are you using node _only_ as a LESS compiler? Try the [OSX app](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I am not running my website from node. It is a php website, but i've read that the php precompiler is much slower than the js, so I was looking into using the node version. Now I am realising that maybe it is a bit overkill to use node.js just for compiling lessCSS... The OSX looks good, but i dont really get the point of it...

Comment: @0al0 the OSX app compiles your less to .css. You only need to compile it when you change your `less` source code. You don't need to compile it every time your php application asks for the css. It's a compile once thing, not a dynamic thing.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a blog post about how to do this. When you try to load styles.css you get the styles.less file compiled on the fly <del>http://programming-perils.com/155/parse-less-files-on-the-fly-and-serve-them-as-css/</del> Sorry page was moved to [here](http://www.jisaacks.com/parse-less-files-on-the-fly-and-serve-them-as-css).